# Behat stopped working SSL error fwrite() laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, behat

I was working with behat laravel and somehow it just stopped working.
I have searched for this error, yet I have not found any solution; 
I keep getting this error

```
[ErrorException]
  fwrite(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
  error:1409F07F:SSL routines:ssl3_write_pending:bad write retry
```

Could anyone please help me with this?

The code is not the problem, it reads X lines and then just says it cannot find what ever I put on that line doesn't matter if it would exist or not.

```
 And I follow "Gebruiker aanmaken"                                  # FeatureContext::clickLink()
    Then I should see "Nieuwe gebruiker aanmaken"                      # FeatureContext::assertPageContainsText()
    And I fill in "Voornaam" with "Jesse"                              # FeatureContext::fillField()
    And I fill in "Achternaam" with "Bessem"                           # FeatureContext::fillField()
    And I fill in "E-Mailadres" with "jesse@jbdevv.nl"                 # FeatureContext::fillField()
    And I fill in "Functie" with "Eigenaar"                            # FeatureContext::fillField()
    And I fill in "Geboortedatum" with "14-07-1994"                    # FeatureContext::fillField()
    And I click on submit button "Aanmaken"                            # FeatureContext::iClickOnSubmitButton()
    Then I should not see "Nieuwe gebruiker aanmaken"                  # FeatureContext::assertPageNotContainsText()
    And I should see "Jesse"                                           # FeatureContext::assertPageContainsText()
    And I should see "Bessem"                                          # FeatureContext::assertPageContainsText()
      The text "Bessem" was not found anywhere in the text of the current page. (Behat\Mink\Exception\ResponseTextException)
    And I should see "jesse@jbdevv.nl"                                 # FeatureContext::assertPageContainsText()
    And I should see "Eigenaar"                                        # FeatureContext::assertPageContainsText()
    And I should see "14-07-1994"                                      # FeatureContext::assertPageContainsText()
    And I should see "Er is een e-mail verstuurd naar Jesse@jbdevv.nl" # FeatureContext::assertPageContainsText()



  [ErrorException]
  fwrite(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
  error:1409F07F:SSL routines:ssl3_write_pending:bad write retry
```

this is the exact way the error occurs, i know i should see the last name, when i manually do it i can see the last name, but somehow it gets stuck and just trows that error, if i would remove the line see jesse it would succeed on see bessem and trows an error at the next one wich would be the email

and finally after some more digging

```
ErrorException in StreamBuffer.php line 232:
fwrite(): SSL: Broken pipe
in StreamBuffer.php line 232
at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'fwrite(): SSL: Broken pipe', '/home/vagrant/aag/code/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php', '232', array('bytes' => 'QUIT ', 'bytesToWrite' => '6', 'totalBytesWritten' => '0'))
at fwrite(resource, 'QUIT ') in StreamBuffer.php line 232
```

i still do not know the source of the problem though,

Comment: You need to provide some sort of context for this error.  What is being run when this is thrown?

Comment: this error is being thrown when executing the behat tests, so when using vendor/bin/behat it runs fine on the pc of my colleague, it ran fine on mine, but the problem just occured out of nowhere and now keeps happening

Comment: That doesn't narrow it down... the behat tests could be testing anything.

Comment: well okay, we're testing a system where behat logs in as administrator, creates a user, takes control over the user ( wich is built in the system) tries to create an object for that user. but i get the SSL error when before he gets to the page for logging is as that user, yet if i remove that script, it just gets stuck on creating the user, while if i do include it the user DOES get made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so for if people would have similar problems using behat on dev environment.
Dont be like me, dont use SMTP but use log as MAil_DRIVER in your .env file,

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a sleep(5) just before the fwrite().
It should work just fine after that.

If you'd like to make it a bit more advanced you could try to check for the SSL_Write to return with SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE or SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ, and repeat the call to SSL_write with the same parameters again.

Comment: Bummer... Worked when I had this error. Hopefully someone more experienced will be able to help you.

Comment: i think i might have seen your post when searching for this, thank you for trying tho :)